# How to create an internal numbering of occurrences with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I create a new column (inCount) with numbering of occurrences in a specific column?
Here is an example:

```
id      name        inCount
1       Orly        1
2       Ernest      1
3       Rachel      1
4       Don         1
5       Don         2
6       Ernest      2
7       Angela      1
8       Ernest      3
9       David       1
10      Rachel      2
11      Sully       1
12      Sully       2
13      Rachel      3
14      David       2
15      David       3
16      Kevin       1
17      Kevin       2
18      Orly        2
19      Angela      2
20      Sully       3
21      Kevin       3
22      Don         3
23      Orly        3
24      Angela      3
```

Don from id 5 is numbered 2 because Don appears in id 4 too.
Don from id 22 is numbered 3 due to the above preceding occurrences.

I use MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Express edition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT id, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY id)
  FROM table
 ORDER BY id
```

EDIT: Added order by clause on the select in order to show results in same order indicated by OP.  The ORDER BY in the ROW_NUMBER did not change the outcome, but I changed to id as it will keep the row_number correct for the sample data.

Comment: He's going to order by the `id`, not the `name`, to get the desired numbering.  Ordering by `name` _may_ (as in, the behaviour is potentially undefined) result in different `id`s being labelled with the given incremented `inCount`.

Comment: @X-Zero - I was concerned about that myself, but I ran a quick test and the outcome was not impacted as long as order by was specified for the select.  I can see that the results might not be 100%, so I agree - it should be order by id in the row_number clause.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `partition by`, like:

```
select  row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as inCount
,       *
from    YourTable
order by
        id
```